# all Images gets deleted instead of that particular image whose delete icon is clicked in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my rent detail editing page, there is an image upload for user updating their images or remove previously uploaded images which are fetched from **previousFile()** and can further add images. Further added images are shown from **onDrop() and showFiles()**. I have defined **handleRemove()** for removing the images but they are not working properly.All images gets deleted instead of that particular image which user want to delete. What might be the reason for this?

[image]

**Code is shortened**

```
export default class RoomDetail extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { rooms:[], isEditing:false };
        this.pk = this.props.data.pk;
    }

    componentDidMount(newUser){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/api/rentals/'+this.props.data.pk+'/',
            type:'put',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:JSON.stringify(newUser),
            success: (data) => {
                console.log('data',data);
              },
              error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
              }
            });
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.loadRoomFromServer();
    }

    loadRoomFromServer(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/api/rentals/'+this.props.data.pk,
            dataType:'json',
            success: (data) => {
                console.log('data',data);
                this.setState({rooms: data});
              },
              error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
              }
            });
    }

     handleRemove(id){
      const files = this.state.rooms.gallery.slice();
      this.setState({rooms:files.splice(id,1)});
     }

    renderRoomDetailSection(){
      let url = this.pk;
      let imageFile;
        let firstImage;
        if(this.state.rooms.gallery){
            firstImage = this.state.rooms.gallery[0].image;
            console.log('firstImage', firstImage);
            imageFile = _.map(this.state.rooms.gallery, (image) => {
            return(
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <img src={image.image} key={image.id} className="img-fluid img-rounded" />
                    </div>
                );
            });
        }
        if (this.state.isEditing ){
            return(
                    <EditRent 
                        ownerName={this.state.rooms.ownerName}
                        email = {this.state.rooms.email}
                        phoneNumber = {this.state.rooms.phoneNumber}
                        image = {this.state.rooms.gallery}
                        onRemove = {this.handleRemove.bind(this)}
                        pk={this.props.data.pk} />
                )
        }
                return(
                        <div className="detailListing">
                         here is the rent details 
                       </div>
                )
    }

    renderUserAction(){
        if ( this.state.isEditing ){
            return(
                    save and cancel button is here
                );

        }

        return(
                <div className = "buttons">
                 edit button is here
                </div>
            );
        }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className = "newRoomDetail" >
                 { this.renderRoomDetailSection() }
                 { this.renderUserAction() }
            </div>
        );
    }
    }

var fieldValues = {
  ownerName:'name',
  email:'email@gmail.com',
  phoneNumber:'9842333333'
}


class EditRent extends React.Component{
 constructor(props,context) {
        super(props,context);
        this.state = {
            step: 1
        };
        this.pk = this.props.pk;
    }

  saveValues(field_value) {
    return function() {
      fieldValues = Object.assign({}, fieldValues, field_value)
    }()
  }

  nextStep(step) {
    var step = this.state.step;
    var newStep = step+1;
    this.setState({step:newStep});
  }

  previousStep(step) {
    var step = this.state.step;
    var newStep = step-1
    this.setState({
      step : newStep
    });
  }

  showStep() {
  switch (this.state.step) {
    case 1:
      return <RenderPersonalInfo fieldValues={fieldValues}
                            ownerName={this.props.ownerName}
                            email={this.props.email}
                            phoneNumber={this.props.phoneNumber}
                            nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)}
                            previousStep={this.previousStep.bind(this)}
                            saveValues={this.saveValues.bind(this)} />
    case 2:
      return <RenderPhotos fieldValues={fieldValues}
                           image={this.props.image}
                           nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)}
                           previousStep={this.previousStep.bind(this)}
                           imageRemove={this.props.onRemove}
                           pk={this.props.pk} />
  }
}

  render() {

    return (
      <main className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <span className="progress-step">Step {this.state.step}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {this.showStep()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    )
  }
};

 let image = [];
 class RenderPhotos extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            files: []
        };
    }

    handleClick(image){
      this.props.imageRemove(image);
    }

    onDrop(files) {
      console.log('Received files: ', files);
      this.setState({
          files: files
      });

      image = new FormData(files);
      $.each(files,function(i,file){
        image.append('image',file);
      });

    }

    previousFile(){
      return(
          <ul className="gallery">
            {
             _.map(this.props.image, (image,idx) => {
                      return(
                          <li className="col-md-3" key={idx}>
                            <span className="remove"><i onClick= onClick= {this.handleClick.bind(this,image)} className = "fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <img src={image.image} key={image.id} className="img-fluid img-rounded" />
                          </li>
                        )
                    })
            }
          </ul>
        )
    }

    showFiles() {
        const { files } = this.state;
        if (!files.length) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Dropped files: </h3>
                <ul className="gallery">
                    {
                        _.map(files, (file, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <li className="col-md-3" key={idx}>
                                    <img src={file.preview} width={200}/>
                                    <div>{file.name}</div>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })

                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
      return (
           <div>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                <form method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>
                  <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
                          style={style}
                          activeStyle={activeStyle}
                          accept="image/*">
                    Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
                </Dropzone>
              </form>
                { this.previousFile() }
                { this.showFiles() }

              </div>
              <div className="row continueBtn text-right">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-left" onClick={this.props.previousStep.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-hand-o-left"></i></button>
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-right" onClick={this.nextStep.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-floppy-o"></i></button>
               </div>
            </div>

      );
    }
}
```

**Remove part is in RenderPhotos component**.

Comment: for the first time in my life i am not seeing any developers commenting or aswering here :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you try to remove images that comes from the props (previousFile) by setting them in the local state. That approach would work if you would render the images from the local state instead but what you do is that you render directly from props which will cause React to not see any changes. To make the image removal to work you will need to move the removal logic to the parent component and supply the child with a function to trigger the deletion.

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      files: []
    };
  }

  handleRemove(id) {
    const files = this.state.files.slice();
    this.seState({
      files: files.splice(id, 1)
    });
  }

  render() {
      return <Files files={this.state.files} onRemove={this.handleRemove.bind(this)} />;
    }
}

function handleClick(id, props) {
  props.handleRemove(id);
}

function Files(props) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {props.files.map(
         (file, key) => <li key={key} onClick={handleClick.bind(this, key, props)}>{file.name}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
}
```

Comment: so in my case i have to update rooms object, right? because image and other values are loaded to rooms object.

Comment: I have updated my code. When i click on delete icon, instead of deleting the particular image it deletes all the images .

Comment: if i try to delete any one of the image all the images gets deleted.